# CSS optimizer to convert in shorthand form?

Tags: css, optimization, compression

Is there any free online or offline tool to optimize all properties to shorthand form, wherever is possible?

it would be useful to compress big files.

**For example:**

This

```
.class {
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

to this

```
.class {
padding: 0 10px 15px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Awww man. Why would one want to mutilate their CSS like that? Just to save the twenty bytes per rule?

Comment: CSSTidy would be a good choice, but it requires dowload and command-lining. http://www.codebeautifier.com is hands-down the best online compressor(imo)

Comment: I'd like to find the reverse of this: something to convert cryptic shorthand to clear standardhand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two snippets of CSS are not identical. The second one explicitly sets the top padding to zero, but the first one does not set a top padding so will inherit whatever was specified before.

For example, if you apply the class to a paragraph that already has padding, in the first situation the paragraph will keep its top padding, but in the second you remove it.

So there isn't going to be a tool that does exactly what you want. You'll simply need to write your CSS properly in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Cleancss](http://www.cleancss.com/), this is an online tool.

By using your example:

```
   Input: 0.096KB, Output: 0.038KB, Compression Ratio: 60.4% (-58 Bytes)
```

Comment: I am not sure if it can do what OP wants.

Comment: but it doesn't work if `.class {
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-left: 20px;
}`

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas:  I have not seen anyone that adds value to 0 if it is not in the original css source ... CSSTidy is open source, so it should be very easy to add such rules. Possible it is possible with CSSTidy template too, but I'm not sure if possible.